# Uniqueness of Singular Value Decomposition.

Tags: linear-algebra

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs322/2008sp/stuff/TrefethenBau_Lec4_SVD.pdf

This is from Trefethen's book Numerical Linear Algebra. I am having trouble with something (from page 30).

> Since $||A||_2 = \sigma_1$, $||Av_2|| \leq\sigma_1$;

This I am ok with, then

> But this must be an equality, for otherwise, since $w = cv_1 + sv_2$ for some constants $c,s$ with $|s|^2 + |c|^2 = 1$, we would have $||Aw||_2 < \sigma_1$.

This I am having trouble showing to be true. (I think)
$$||w||_2^2 = ||cv_1 + sv_2||_2^2 = |s|^2 + |c|^2 = 1$$
is fine, since $v_1,v_2$ are orthogonal. But,
$$||Aw||_2^2 = ||cAv_1+sAv_2||_2^2 = (cAv_1+sAv_2)^*(cAv_1+sAv_2) $$$$= |c|^2||Av_1||_2 + |s|^2||Av_2||_2 + 2cs(Av_1)^*(Av_2)$$
$$= |c|^2|\sigma_1|^2 + |s|^2||Av_2||_2 + 2cs(Av_1)^*(Av_2)$$
$$<|\sigma_1|^2(|c|^2 + |s|^2) + 2cs(Av_1)^*(Av_2) = |\sigma_1|^2 + 2cs(Av_1)*(Av_2)$$

I need to somehow conclude that $(Av_1)^*(Av_2) = 0$.
taking the square root of both sides then gives us the result. I think I am a little confused because page 7 of

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-335j-introduction-to-numerical-methods-fall-2004/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf

says 
$$||Aw||_2 = ||cAv_1||_2+||sAv_2||_2$$

which would imply that $(Av_1)^*(Av_2) = 0$. How does one conclude that $(Av_1)^*(Av_2) = 0$?

There is nothing special about $A$, so I can not see why this would be the case.

Comment: It is not generally true that $\|u + v\|^2 \leq \|u\|^2+ \|v\|^2$.

Comment: Nor is it true that $(a + b)^2 \leq a^2 + b^2$ for $a,b\geq 0$

Comment: Really, I just don't understand how you justify those inequalities

Comment: You are right, what a stupid mistake. Jesus.